# Regex returns undefined with underscore group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings like this:

```
123a-124b.csv
123a_124b.csv
123-124b.csv
123_124.csv
```

I need to match the numbers only with a regex, so I've tried these 2 regexes with javascript:

```
/^(\d+)\w*(?:.(\d+)\w*)?\.CSV$/i
/^(\d+)\w*(?:[-|_](\d+)\w*)?\.CSV$/i
```

Running `exec` on this gives the correct result for `-` but a `_` matches, but returns `undefined for the second named group`. In fact, the first regex works with any char except `_`. For example `123a=123b.csv` works correctly.

Any idea what's wrong.

Some more example outputs:

```
var TEST = /^(\d+)\w*(?:.(\d+)\w*)?\.CSV$/i;
> undefined
TEST.exec('123a_123b.csv')
> ["123a_123b.csv", "123", undefined]
TEST.exec('123a+123b.csv')
> ["123a+123b.csv", "123", "123"]
TEST.exec('123a=123b.csv')
> ["123a=123b.csv", "123", "123"]
TEST.exec('123a?123b.csv')
> ["123a?123b.csv", "123", "123"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(\d+)[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:.(\d+)\w*)?\.CSV$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/44

The problem with your regex is `^(\d+)\w*(?:_(\d+)\w*)?\.CSV$`

```
                               ^^^
```

This `\w*` will consume everything and the second group will never get a chance to come into play.Change `\w` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to exclude `_` from matching as it acts as delimter here to your second group